# Create duplicate dataframes from list of existing dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Updated for Clarity**

Task

- Create a set of duplicate dataframes with a different set of names, such as item28, item30, item31...item38.
- After creating the new copies, I then have to modify the contents of specific columns.

Current Process

- Step 1: Create new dataframes by copying the original:

```
item28 = item1.copy(); 
item29 = item2.copy(); 
item30 = item3.copy(); 
item31 = item4.copy(); 
item32 = item5.copy(); 
item33 = item6.copy(); 
item34 = item7.copy(); 
item35 = item8.copy(); 
item36 = item9.copy(); 
item37 = item10.copy(); 
item38 = item11.copy();
```

- Step 2. Modify the columns in the new data frame:
  `item28['indicator_number'] = 28;`

Goal

- Reproduce this manual process in a dynamic, Pythonic way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you call `id(item1)` and `id(item28)` do they give you the same number for both dataframes?

Comment: Your "duplicates" are only references to the originals, not standalone copies. If you modify a "duplicate", you're going to see that modification in the original. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: how are the variables generated? feel like a simple refactor upstream could help you more

Comment: This statement doesn't make sense: "These dataframes are created elsewhere in the program and have to be duplicated after the fact, otherwise, I would create a copy" -- you can create a copy at any time.

Answer (score 1):

The "Pythonic" way to generate your duplicates:

```py
list_of_copies = [df.copy() for df in list_of_originals]
```

Note the use of `.copy()` -- this is necessary because otherwise you're just creating duplicate *references* to the same dataframes. Any change made in the "duplicate" would be reflected in the original which is almost certainly not what you want (otherwise what would be the point?).

If you similarly have a list of values you want to use to update the dataframe copies:

```py
for new_value, df in zip(list_of_values, list_of_copies):
    df["indicator_number"] = new_value
```

Right now it's not super clear what you're trying to do here, so I'm kinda just grasping at straws. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: @oda [`deep` defaults to `True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Comment: Apologies, I only skimmed the answer and realized after-the-fact that you were applying the `copy` method of a `df` as opposed to a `list`.